# "Check back in the New Year" -> does that mean January, or any time next year?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read the following sentence:

> We are looking in to creating a new hands-free model. Check back in the New Year.

Does that imply that more information regarding the new hands-free model will likely be released in January, or any time next year?

Comment: It means merely during the next calendar year. Some will infer from the capitalized _New Year_ that the information will be released soon after the holiday by that name, however. It's typical market-speak which, translated, means _We want you to breathlessly await our product, but we have no idea when our developers will be willing to release it._

Comment: It doesn't mean much, because it's not something a native speaker would be likely to say.

Comment: @AlanCarmack is that a reason for downvote?

Comment: I don't see how asking about a phrase that is not idiomatic is useful to other learners here

Comment: @AlanCarmarck Googling "Check back in the New Year" shows many results: maybe some people would be interested to know it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase

> check back in the new year

would usually mean the early part of the coming year, not necessarily only January, but is also a phrase which allows some leeway in case schedules and time tables slip.

If a friend were to say to you

> I don't have the answer now, check back with me in the new year.

that would probably mean January.

However, if a company is preannouncing a new product, it could mean "any time in the following year".  Usually additional news releases would be made closer to the  product announcement date as the company tries to manage expectations.

Comment: Thanks! One of the commenter said that the expression "check back in the new year" is not idiomatic. Do you agree?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it, "*in the new year*" is just a phrase to describe a period of time, just as "check back *after lunch*", "check back *tomorrow*", "check back *later*", "check back *next week*", "check back *after new year's*" are all correct for defining a later time.  "In the new year" is very nonspecific in terms of time, but one could also say "check back *in your next life*" if you wanted to get rid of someone.

Answer (score 0):

Google defines New year as "the calendar year just begun or about to begin."
Or "the calendar year just begun or about to begin." Or finally "the period immediately before and after 31 December.".
So if there is a mention about New Year it has to be one of the mentioned. If not the company could have merely said "check back Next Year" or check back the coming year".
Thank you!